# is there a way to automate OpenStack Swift operations with Ansible

Tags: ansible, openstack-swift

I'm currently working on developing an OpenStack based private cloud offering, and a question of Swift automation came up.
We are using Ansible to automate Nova compute tasks, and I was wandering if there was an Ansible module for automating Swift operations.
In particular, I'm interested in automation of creating Nova volume backups to Swift, using Ansible (if that makes sense)
Does anyone have such experience at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that sounds stupid, but did you google for it?

One of the first things I have found is [swiftacular](http://serverascode.com/2014/03/21/swiftacular-openstack-swift-with-ansible.html). Not sure it can do what you want, because I'm not familiar with OpenStack.

Here is a video directly from openstack.org which should be quite interesting I guess: [Taming OpenStack with Ansible](https://www.openstack.org/summit/openstack-summit-atlanta-2014/session-videos/presentation/taming-openstack-with-ansible)

Here is another OpenStack playbook/roles construct, which contains some Swift tasks: https://github.com/openstack-ansible/openstack-ansible